# Putnam problem with suggested solution

Tags: vectors, contest-math, physics

A Putnam question:

A particle of unit mass moves on a straight line under the action of a force which is a function $f(v)$ of the velocity $v$ of a particle, but the form of this function is not known. A motion is observed, and the distance $x$ covered in time $t$ is found to be $x = at + bt^2 + ct^3$, where a, b and c have numerical values determined by observing the motion. Find the function $f(v)$ for the range of $v$ covered by the experiment.

I reasoned that since $F=ma$ and the force is $f(v)$, then $x'' = v' = a = {f(v) \over 1}$ and $x'' = 2b + 6ct$, so $f(v) = 2b +6ct,$ where $m=1$ is the mass of the particle. Is that correct? If not, please provide a correct solution.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks, fixed

Comment: As Igor Rivin points out, you need a function of $v$. The thing that comes to mind is using $v = x' = 3ct^2+2bt+a$, then solving for $t$ in $3ct^2+2bt+(a-v) = 0$, and using that in $f(v) = 2b+6ct$, but I haven't thought through whether that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assume for simplicity that $m=1$. Then we have $x''=f(x')$, since $x''$ is the acceleration and $x'$ is the speed.
You can re-write this as
$$
6ct+2b=f(a+2bt+3ct^2).
$$
Let $s=a+2bt+3ct^2$, then
$$
t=\frac{ -b\pm \sqrt {(b^2-3ca)+3cs}}{3c}
$$
and thus
$$
6ct+2b=\pm 2\sqrt {(b^2-3ca)+3cs}
$$
Assuming that $f$ is positive, we get
$$
f(s)=2\sqrt {(b^2-3ca)+3cs}
$$